# Ignore specified absolute directories with tab completion?

Tags: command-line, directory

I work on a cluster with many users. There are 50 users on the cluster with the same first letter as my username, and a user who has the same name up to the last letter. When I tab complete from `/home/e` I'd like to see just `/home/elsherbini/`, rather than having to type a few more characters, tab, and then type the last one.

It seems FIGNORE doesn't work on absolute paths, only file suffixes. Is there a way to ignore a curated list of directories for tab completion?

*GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)*

Comment: If it's just for your home directory, type `~` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One way I'd suggest is to have an `alias` if we are just concerned about the `home` directory path, adding the below to your `profile` would help here, whatever unique alias you made should autocomplete with even a first character.

```
alias myHome="cd /home/elsherbini"
. .profile
my\T
pwd
/home/elsherbini
```

**EDIT:**

The other way could be **binding a key** but even this would require a quick `double click` and `right click`, considering your usage in `PuTTY`, if this helps.

```
completeIt(){ echo "elsherbini"; }
bind -x '"\C-h": completeIt;'
```

Use of `Control-H` would prompt your customized string, say your user-name.
Usage:

```
$ cd
elsherbini
```

Comment: this could work. I'd prefer to be able to just think about the filesystem without the extra step of remembering to use the alias. Also we have other folders for data storage, processing, etc, so i'd end up with lots of aliases.

Comment: Updated with another way

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `zsh` which allows completion to be customized very thoroughly. This option prevents certain patterns from completion:

```
autoload -Uz compinit; compinit
# ignore some common patterns that we usually don't want as completions
zstyle ':completion:*' ignored-patterns "/usr/share/iscan" "/usr/lib/iscan" \
        "iscan" "/usr/lib/ispell" "ispell" "/usr/lib64" "/usr/lib32" \
        "/usr/libx32" "/usr/libexec" "/srv/tftp" "chkwins" "dpkg-buildflags"
```

Comment: looks like /bin/zsh is indeed available on the cluster. I might consider switching finally.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the builtin `compgen` for simple directory completions (as for `cd` and `ls`). For example, put this function in your ~/.bashrc

```
compgen(){
    local IFS=$'\n'
    local x tmp
    x=$( builtin compgen "$@" ) &&
    while read -r tmp; do
        [[ "$tmp" =~ ^/home/e && ! "$tmp" =~ ^/home/elsherbini$ ]] ||
        echo "$tmp"
    done <<< "$x"
}
```

It runs the builtin `compgen` and filters the output so that any lines that
begin with the regex `^/home/e` and do not match `^/home/elsherbini$` are
removed from the list of possible completions.  Beware, the regexes are not quoted inside `[[]]`.

Comment: I copied it into my .bashrc and it didn't seem to work as intended. I'm not very savvy with my bash scripting, so i'm not sure how i would proceed.

Comment: Did you start a new bash in the terminal, or reread it with `. ~/.bashrc`?

Comment: yeah, i tried doing both.

Comment: ok. I'm sorry I have a more recent version of bash 4.3.42, and dont have access to an older version, so perhaps there is some feature missing. Does it have no effect at all when you do `cd /home/e` then tab twice? I looked in 
`/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` for the use made by `_filedir()` of compgen in this way.

Comment: yeah, no effect on ` cd /home/e` and tab twice, or even just a bare `/home/e` and tab twice. I tried moving the function both to the top and bottom of the `.bashrc` and saw no difference.